# vb net button do two things

Tags: c#, vb.net

i want my button to color the other buttons And different color the other buttons when it is clicked again(2nd time).... I am trying this code. Please Help me....

```
Private Sub Button1_MouseClick(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles Button1.MouseClick
    Dim visit As Integer = e.Clicks
    visit = 0
    If (visit = 1) Then
        Button2.BackColor = Color.BlueViolet
        Button3.BackColor = Color.Aqua
    ElseIf (visit > 1) Then
        Button2.BackColor = Color.Brown
        Button3.BackColor = Color.Bisque
    End If
    visit += 1
End Sub
```

Comment: Pull `Dim visit As Integer` outside to the class and you will be fine. Don't use `e.Clicks`

Comment: Why are you using MouseClick rather than ButtonClick?  If want White, use White, not those other colors.  And learn about variable Scope

Comment: try using boolean values, (instead of 1 and 0). it will also allow 'toggling' if required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 Dim visit As Integer = 0;
 Private Sub Button1_MouseClick(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles Button1.MouseClick

    If (visit = 0) Then
       Button2.BackColor = Color.BlueViolet
       Button3.BackColor = Color.Aqua
       visit = 1
    ElseIf (visit = 1) Then
       Button2.BackColor = Color.Brown
       Button3.BackColor = Color.Bisque
       visit = 0
    End If

 End Sub
```

Comment: Thanx my dear its realy working...

Answer (score 2):

[`e.Clicks` doesn't do what you think it does.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.mouseeventargs.clicks%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)  It's not tracking the total clicks over the lifetime of the form, just for that one event.  And since `visit` is re-initialized in the scope of the event handler as well, it's always going to re-start for every event.

Track the total clicks outside of that scope.  Something like this:

```
Dim visit as Integer = 0;

Private Sub Button1_MouseClick(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles Button1.MouseClick

    visit += 1

    If (visit = 1) Then
        Button2.BackColor = Color.BlueViolet
        Button3.BackColor = Color.Aqua
    ElseIf (visit > 1) Then
        Button2.BackColor = Color.Brown
        Button3.BackColor = Color.Bisque
    End If

End Sub
```

As long as the class remains in scope, `visit` will continue to increment with each event.  If the class itself is also falling out of scope (such as on a web form) then you'd need to persist `visit` in an even higher scope, potentially even outside the application state itself.

It's also not entirely clear the logic you're trying to express here.  After the first click, that `ElseIf` condition will *always* be true.  Are you just looking to toggle between true/false values instead of incrementing an integer?  Something like this?:

```
Dim visit as Boolean = False;

Private Sub Button1_MouseClick(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles Button1.MouseClick

    visit = Not visit

    If (visit = True) Then
        Button2.BackColor = Color.BlueViolet
        Button3.BackColor = Color.Aqua
    Else
        Button2.BackColor = Color.Brown
        Button3.BackColor = Color.Bisque
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanx my dear its realy working...

Answer (score 1):

An other option is to set your variable as Static. This will keep it's value in memory in between method call.

```
Private Sub Button1_MouseClick(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles Button1.MouseClick
    Static visit As Integer = 0

    visit += 1

    If (visit = 1) Then
        Button2.BackColor = Color.BlueViolet
        Button3.BackColor = Color.Aqua
    ElseIf (visit > 1) Then
        Button2.BackColor = Color.Brown
        Button3.BackColor = Color.Bisque
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanx my dear its realy working...

Answer (score 0):

This will alternate the colour of button2 based on a boolean flag

```
Dim PrevClicked As Boolean = False
Private Sub Button1_Click_1(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    If PrevClicked = False Then
        Button2.BackColor = Color.Black
        PrevClicked = True
    Else
        Button2.BackColor = Color.White
        PrevClicked = False
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanx my dear its realy working...